# shutil.copytree () does not complete the copying process

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have the following code which copies the folder `foler_test` to the folder `destination_folder` for it I use the function `shutil.copytree()` and to show the progress I use a `QProgresBar` but as you can see in the image the progress is not completed:

[image]

**Additional Information:**

the total value of the `folder_test` folder is`2131094117`
but to the terminal the execution of the script the value it throws now is `2384493856`

this is what the cmd shows:

```
C: \ Users \ Angel \ Desktop \ folder_test ------ Result getUbication
2131094117 ------- total_size
C: \ Users \ Angel \ Desktop \ folder_test .-------------- ubicatino
start copy
0 partial
98304 partial
65699748 partial
192151368 partial
382959340 partial
643956368 partial
976715316 partial
1373437400 partial
1841905020 partial
2384493856 final_copydo
finished
```

Supposedly in the cmd the process is finished but the `QProgressBar` has not finished being completed

I hope you can help me:

code.py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic,QtCore
import os,shutil
import threading

class TheThread(QtCore.QThread):
    ActionFinished = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)
    ActionValue = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self,origin,destination,sizeOrigin):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

        self.origin = origin
        self.destination = destination
        self.sizeOrigin = sizeOrigin

    def run(self):
        self.copy()
        self.ActionFinished.emit(True)

    def copy(self):
        print("start copy")
        final_total = 0

        #print(final_total,"final_total",self.sizeOrigin,"total_size_copied")
        while final_total<self.sizeOrigin:
            print(final_total,"parcial")
            for source,dirs,files in os.walk(self.destination):
                for f in files:

                    fp = os.path.join(source,f)
                    final_total = os.path.getsize(fp)+final_total
                    self.ActionValue.emit(int(final_total*100/self.sizeOrigin))
                QtCore.QThread.msleep(100)
        print(final_total,"final_copiado")


class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("test.ui",self)

        self.getUbication()

    def getUbication(self):
        target = 'folder_test'
        initial_folder = "C:\\"
        self.folder_ubication = ""

        for root,dirs,files in os.walk(initial_folder):
            if target in root:
                self.folder_ubication = os.path.join(root)
                break
        print(self.folder_ubication,"------Result getUbication")
        self.getSizeOrigin(self.folder_ubication,self.folder_ubication)


    def getSizeOrigin(self,ubication,ubication2):
        total_size = 0

        for ubication,dirs,files in os.walk(ubication):
            for f in files:
                fp = os.path.join(ubication,f)
                total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)
        print(total_size,"-------total_size")

        self.startThread(total_size,ubication,ubication2)

    def startThread(self,total_size,ubication,ubication2):
        #print(ubication,"value",ubication2)

        destination = 'C:/Users/Angel/Desktop/destination_folder/folder_test'
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.CopyTree,args=(ubication2,destination,))
        t.start()
        self.copyThread = TheThread(ubication2, destination, total_size)
        self.copyThread.ActionValue.connect(self.updateProgressBar)
        self.copyThread.ActionFinished.connect(self.FunctionFinish)
        self.copyThread.start()

    def CopyTree(self,ubication2,destination):
        print(ubication2,".--------------ubicatino")
        shutil.copytree(ubication2, destination)

    def updateProgressBar(self,progress):
        self.Bar.setValue(progress)

    def FunctionFinish(self,state):
        print("finished")

app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
app.exec_()
```

test.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>565</width>
    <height>353</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QProgressBar" name="Bar">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>160</x>
      <y>180</y>
      <width>118</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="value">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>565</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**New Information**

then why the `QProgressBar` stops before and because the size of the copied file is larger than the original file

Comment: What runs in `t.start ()` and what runs in `self.copyThread.start ()` is completely unrelated (independent) processes.
Insert after the line: `shutil.copytree (ubication2, destination)`
 line: `print (" \ nlistdir destination: ", os.listdir (destination))` and wait for it to print.
You will be even more convinced of this if you comment out the line `# QtCore.QThread.msleep (100)`

Comment: @S.Nick, but then why does `QProgressBar` stop before and because the size of the copied file is larger than the original file?

Comment: @S.Nick,but then why does `QProgressBar` stop before and because the size of the copied file is larger than the original file?